# Send newsletter - This newsletter has been sent - but never arrives?

Tags: emails, notifications

I am using the simplenews module to create newsletters and the subscription module to enable users to subscribe to those newsletters.

"Send one test newsletter to the test address" works and the test email receives a newsletter. However, the same email address which the user is registered with, and subscribed to the same newsletter, does not receive an email when the "Send newsletter" option is selected instead of "Send one test newsletter to the test address" the email never gets received.

Why would this be?

By the way, the user in question is subscribed to the Newsletter Category.

Comment: Have you run cron to send the emails?

Comment: Yes, but still nothing :(
@NigelWaters

Comment: What do you see under /admin/content/simplenews? What status has the newsletter? If you go to the database, is there something in the simplenews_mailspool table?

Comment: I have a bunch of newsletters in /admin/content/simplenews and for all of them the published column has a tick in it, and the Sent column has a tick in all rows apart from 3 @Lance